# Taylor coefficients of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm having some trouble trying to prove the following:

Prove that in the Taylor Polynomial of $\:f(x,y)= \sin(xy)$, centered in $(0,0)$ just the coefficients of order $4k-2$ are nonzero, for  $k \in\{1,2,..n\}$

I don't think induction is a good idea, can you give me some ideas?

Comment: Do you know what the Taylor polynomial is in this case?

Comment: What the Taylor polynomial is?, well I found it just for order 5 and I was thinking about giving an argument using some of combinatory to show that I would get zeros. But it just stays as an argument.